# ReactJS + Redux subscribe method mess

Tags: reactjs, redux

Using create-react-app

```
//index.js 
...
export const store = createStore(getChange, applyMiddleware(thunk)) 
//getChange is my reducers name

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();


// Box.js which gets rendered in App.js 

import {store} from '../../../index'
...
const renderagain = () => store.getState()

store.subscribe(renderagain)
...
```

This throws me an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Excuse me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you actually want to achieve by this code snippet? Kindly eleborate So I can help you with appropriate sections

Comment: All i really need is to subscribe to state changes, because the project I'm trying to do now heavily depends on it :(

Comment: You want some store contents (state of the reducer) to be accessed within a component?

Comment: I want to get some stuff rendered programaticly according to the state change, but that happens only once in the componentDidMount. ofc I can write down render scenarios for all the cases of the state, but that's literally the worst thing to do

Comment: okay so the story is, that I want this.props.getarray(this.props.cryptoChange, this.props.valueOfChange) (this is an action, setting a third state to an array of objects) to happen every time any of my states changes

Answer (score 0):

```
//index.js 
...
export const store = createStore(getChange, applyMiddleware(thunk)) 
//getChange is my reducers name

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

the code above is good to be used to create a store with some reducers combined. and also providing that tot he whole application by passing it into the Provider Component wrapping the Application. This makes the redux actions and store contents available to access for the component. There you can subscribe the store to et notified on changes in store, or on action dispatches.

You are using the callback to subscribe in a wrong way. You might use it this way:

```
function select(state) {
  return state.some.deep.property
}
​
let currentValue
function handleChange() {
  let previousValue = currentValue
  currentValue = select(store.getState())
​
  if (previousValue !== currentValue) {
    console.log(
      'Some deep nested property changed from',
      previousValue,
      'to',
      currentValue
    )
  }
}
​
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange)
unsubscribe()
```

For further documentation and queries you can see this. https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribe-listener

Answer (score 0):

It's a circular dependency issue.

`index.js` imports `App.js`, which eventually imports `Box.js`.  But, `Box.js` is attempting to `import {store} from "../../index.js`", which is wrong in several ways.

Your component files **should not** be attempting to import the store directly, and definitely should not be attempting to import values from `index.js`.  You also shouldn't be trying to subscribe to the store directly in your component files.

Instead, use the React-Redux `connect()` function in your components to create wrappers that manage the process of subscribing to the store for you.  Then, use the connected components, and they'll automatically use the store you passed to `<Provider>`.

Comment: you mean if I want to connect the Box component I should do tosmething like export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Box) then I automaticly subscribe to the store?

Comment: Yep, exactly.  Also see [my slides on how to use React-Redux properly](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/presentations/workshops/redux-fundamentals/react-redux.html).